# Hibernate misplace auto increment when generating schema

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Agenda implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private PessoaFisica pessoaFisica;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Preferencia preferencia;

}
```

witch generates this table:

```
create table agenda (   
        id bigint not null, 
        preferencia_id bigint not null auto_increment, 
        pessoa_fisica_id bigint not null, 
        primary key (preferencia_id, pessoa_fisica_id, id)
);
```

I have used multiple @ids before, but this is the first time that I needed an auto increment field.  Why auto increment is being misplaced?

Comment: Are you sure you want all 3 fields to be `@Id` fields (ie parts of the primary key)?

Comment: The ID field is sufficient to uniquely identify the entity. It should be the only ID field.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, they need to be unique and foreign keys should be created as pk in my project in this case.

Comment: @JBNizet I need the 3 of them to be unique.

Comment: @user1459479, unique does not necessarily mean these fields have to be part of primary key. Do you really need to identify a row in the table by id,preferencia_id and pessoa_fisica_id, or just 'id' will also uniquely identify the row?

Comment: @rootkit Yes, I could just set them as unique, but the spec tell me to do so. That's the DBA rules.